# cofinite filter and intersection of the closure of its elements

Tags: general-topology

In my topology book there is the following exercise.

Let $X$ be a infinite set with the cofinite topology. Show that the set $G=\{X\setminus M\mid M\text{ finite subset of } X\}$ is a filter and determine the set $A= \bigcap_{(X\setminus M) \in G} \overline{X\setminus M}$.

Showing that $G$ is a filter I have done easily, but I am unsure about the second part. I think $A=X$ because $x\in A\Leftrightarrow  \forall\; U\in \mathcal{U}(x)\;\forall\; X\setminus M\in G\text{ we have } U\cup (X\setminus M)\neq \emptyset$, where $\mathcal{U}(x)$ is the set of all the neighbourhood of $x$. Then, this intersection should always be non empty. Am I right or do I miss something? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If $A\subseteq X$ is infinite, what is $\overline{A}$? By definition, it is the smallest closed set containing $A$.

But what *are* the closed subsets of the cofinite topology? They are sets whose complement is open. So they are $X$ and finite sets. So if $A$ is infinite, there is only one closed set containing $A$.

From here, it should be apparent what this intersection ends up being.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. $A$ is infinite and $A\subset \overline{A}$, $\overline{A}$ is a closed set so it is either $X$ or a finite set. A finite set cannot be because $A$ infinite is not contained in a finite set. Then $\overline{A}=X$. So the intersection I am looking for is $X$. Right?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea.

Comment: Ok, ,thanks a lot for making it clear